# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 : Abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting error while building a new java project in Intellij IDEA.

> Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=3288551993288229307 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djps.file.types.component.name=CommunityFileTypes -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2016.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\amit.IdeaIC2016.3\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\amit.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/amit/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_121 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/amit/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/compile-server/*temp* -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-7908862111513713438-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/maven/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/maven/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49678 caa34c31-1fea-4db7-948b-fa86d64868f9 C:/Users/amit/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/compile-server

Could not identify what the exact error is, tried searching for the same someone suggested to rollback NVedia Driver update to fix this, tried that but no luck.

Please suggest if someone has faced the same issue...

Comment: Does it help if you install Nvidia driver 378.66 and reboot?

Comment: Surprisingly..it worked thanks @CrazyCoder

Comment: Great, you can accept the answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating to the latest nvidia driver should help.

The problem was fixed in the 378.57 hotfix update and in 378.66 release driver version.

Comment: In Linux same process?

Answer (score 0):

Change build to build no check error in the current project run/debug configuration